# getting json data from ajax post

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, ashx

I am trying to get json data from my jquery ajax in ashx file, but result is somehow unusable. how can I get and bind it to dynamic or alternative?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    var result = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

**result**

> maintype=Entity.JobApplication&feeds=&fields%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=EmployeeRequest&fields%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=1&fields%5B1%5D%5Bkey%5D=State&fields%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=1&fields%5B2%5D%5Bkey%5D=FirstName&fields%5B2%5D%5Bvalue%5D=11&fields%5B3%5D%5Bkey%5D=LastName&fields%5B3%5D%5Bvalue%5D=22

```
**json data**

var data = {
  "maintype": "Entity.JobApplication",
  "feeds": "",
  "fields": [
    {
      "key": "EmployeeRequest",
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "key": "State",
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "key": "FirstName",
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "key": "LastName",
      "value": ""
    }
  ]
};


var data = <%=AjaxJSON%>;

for (var i in data.fields)
{
    var o = $("[prop=" + data.fields[i].key + "]");
    data.fields[i].value = o.val();
}
genericAjax("/_Handler/CreateEntity.ashx", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WebUtility.UrlDecode` to decode your string.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    var result =WebUtility.UrlDecode(new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd());
}
```

Result:

> maintype=Entity.JobApplication&feeds=&fields[0][key]=EmployeeRequest&fields[0][value]=1&fields[1][key]=State&fields[1][value]=1&fields[2][key]=FirstName&fields[2][value]=11&fields[3][key]=LastName&fields[3][value]=22

By the way, the data you get is not Json-ready format.

Here you can parse it to more close to json (Add reference: System.Web, System.Web.Extension):

```
string s = "maintype=Entity.JobApplication&feeds=&fields%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=EmployeeRequest&fields%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=1&fields%5B1%5D%5Bkey%5D=State&fields%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=1&fields%5B2%5D%5Bkey%5D=FirstName&fields%5B2%5D%5Bvalue%5D=11&fields%5B3%5D%5Bkey%5D=LastName&fields%5B3%5D%5Bvalue%5D=22";
var dict = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);
var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                    dict.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k]));
```

You will get:

> {"maintype":"Entity.JobApplication","feeds":"","fields[0][key]":"EmployeeRequest","fields[0][value]":"1","fields[1][key]":"State","fields[1][value]":"1","fields[2][key]":"FirstName","fields[2][value]":"11","fields[3][key]":"LastName","fields[3][value]":"22"}

Do a few more step you can convert it to json.

Comment: why its not and how can I turn it to that?

Comment: Here is [Json format description](http://json.org). If the string you get is from your server app, you must turn it to json from server side. If it is from external app, you have to parse the string yourself. There are some article about parse http query, but not directly parse to json.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `JSON.stringify(data)`

```
genericAjax("/_Handler/CreateEntity.ashx", JSON.stringify(data));
```